# Automapper with nested child containers

Tags: c#, automapper

According to author's post in version 2.0

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/29/automapper-2-0-nestedchild-containers/

but this test doesnt work, can someone point out whats wrong here ?

for the test to pass, automapper must call the code passed in ConstructServicesUsing, which it is not

```
    public class Source
    {
        public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public Destination() { }

        public Destination(bool value)
        {
            this.WasCustom = true;
        }
        public bool WasCustom { get; private set; }
        public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void can_make_servicelocator_work()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
        var source = new Source { SomeValue = 100 };
        var dest = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source,
            (option) => option.ConstructServicesUsing((t) => new Destination(true)));
        Assert.IsTrue(dest.WasCustom);
    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to have happen?  You seem very confused.  Your code makes no sense.

Comment: i thought you will read the code, anyways, i want the test to pass, its failing now, for it to pass, the constructor with boolean arg would have to be called, which is not being called, the way to call it is using the constructor func passed during map call ( as opposed to during Initializing the configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i asked the same question on automapper forum, and according to the author, this would be available in 2.1

[here](http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/37e54253462c532) is the link

Comment: I tried this with 2.2.1 and it the test from above still fails?